# Playwright (Puppeteer) context is an empty array at launch?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, chromium, playwright

When using puppeteer, i used to get new tab by using this lines of code:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
const [page] = await browser.pages()

await page.goto('http://example.com')
```

The main purpose of this is the fewer tabs number, my app is running lighter.
But when i using playwright, it seems that the context isn't contain any page yet.

```
const browser = await playwright.chromium.launch()
const context = await browser.newContext()
const [page] = await context.pages()

await page.goto('http://example.com')
```

My code is running, but i keep getting this error message:

> (node:47248) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'goto' of undefined

Am i the only one who getting this kind of error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the same behavior you would get in puppeteer if you use `createIncognitoBrowserContext`.

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const context = await browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext();
const [page] = await context.pages(); //Page is null here

await page.goto('http://example.com');
```

Both `createIncognitoBrowserContext` in puppeteer and `newContext` in playwright are created with no pages.

As you mentioned in your answer, you could use the default context or call `newPage` in the context you just created.

Comment: A little bit confusing at first, but now it's getting make sense. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After trying to get this error gone, i'm getting the code to be like this:

```
const browser = await playwright.chromium.launch()
const context = await browser.defaultContext()
const [page] = await context.pages()

await page.goto('http://example.com')
```

I change `newContext()` to `defaultContext()`.